# A basic question on convergence in prob. and a.s. convergence

Tags: probability-theory

If random variables $X_n$ are dominated by an integrable random variable then $E[X_n]\to E[X]$ follows if $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability.

Proof: Take any subsequence $\{E[X_{n_k}]\}$. I need to show that it converges to $E[X]$. Now I know that $X_{n_k}$ contains a further subsequence $X_{n_k(i)} $where almost sure convergence is guranteed. and so, $E[X_{n_k(i)}]\to E[X]$. We can say upto this much. But, I have to prove $\{E[X_{n_k}]\} \to E[X]$ . How to proceed from here.

Comment: Look for a proof of Dominated Convergence Theorem. Convergence in probability can be even relaxed to convergence in distribution...

Comment: @d.k.o: I am trying to prove convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution. So, I want to show $\int fd\mu_n -> \int fd\mu$ for a bounded continuous function $f$. Here $\int fd\mu_n = E[f(X_n)]$ and $\int fd\mu=E[f(X)]$. Now, I know that $X_n ->_p X$ implies $f(X_n) ->_p f(X)$.

Comment: So, you may show that for any $\epsilon$ $|E(f(X_n)-f(X))|\le E|f(X_n)-f(X)|=E[|f(X_n)-f(X)|1\{|X_n-X|<\epsilon\}]+E[|f(X_n)-f(X)|1\{|X_n-X| \ge \epsilon\}]] \rightarrow 0 as n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @d.k.o.: I want to use the following theorem : A necessary and sufficient condition for $X_n ->_p X$ is that each subsequence $\{X_{n_k}\}$ contain a further subsequence $\{X_{n_k}\}$ such that $\{X_{n_k}\} -> X$ with probability 1 as $n -> \infty$.

Comment: @d.k.o.: The above is given as hint in Billingsley. It must be something very easy I am missing.

Comment: @d.k.o.: yes. I just mentioned the step where I was stuck.

Comment: @d.k.o.: no, in order to show that $E[X_n] -> E[X]$ i want a.s convergence for $X_n$, not subsequence. Or, I can try to show convergence of $\{E[X_{n_k}]\}$, then I have a.s. convergence of a subsubsequence. So, for each sequence we have a.s. convergence for a subsequence. No way to proceed from here.

Comment: You wrote "But I have to prove $E[X_{n_k}] \rightarrow E[X]$" So , you get it...

Comment: @d.k.o.: To prove that a sequence converges it is enough to show that every subsequence of it converges. I am just trying that. So, I took one subsequence and tried to prove it convergence.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Fatou's lemma and the dominating random variable to get the next sandwich:

$$
\mathsf{E}\liminf_n|X_n|\le \liminf_n\mathsf{E}|X_n|\le \limsup_n\mathsf{E}|X_n|\le \mathsf{E}\limsup_n|X_n|.
$$

2. Convergence $X_n\xrightarrow{d}X$ (or $X_n\xrightarrow{p}X$) and (1) imply your result.

Comment: I did not understand the second point. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: It's about Skorohod representation theorem: there is $Y_n\rightarrow_{a.s.}Y$ with the same distribution as $X$'s.

Comment: What purpose does claim 1. serve in proving the proposition?